# How to mock big ArrayList by Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, arraylist, mockito

I am going to make method which will analyze big ArrayList. and I want to write test method in JUnit. The size of ArrayList could reach up to couple of millions. I think that it is not good idea to connect to the database and get datas from there for analyzing because a test is not a unit test if it talks to the database. So how should I act correctly in this situation? Or how big datas are analyzed by unit tests generally?

Example:

```
public void analyze(List<Double> list) {

    double n1, n2, n3;

    for (int i = 3; i < list.size(); i += 3) {

        n1 = list.get(i - 3);
        n2 = list.get(i - 2);
        n3 = list.get(i - 1);

        if (/* Some condition here using n1, n2, n3*/) {
            list.remove(i);
        }
    }
}

@Test
public void analyzeTest() {

    List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();

    // To add 1M data here.

    analyze(list);

    assertEquals(list, expected);

}
```

Comment: please leave comment when you vote negatively.

Comment: Why do you need a mock at all? It should be fine to just create a normal `ArrayList` and fill it with a million entries manually during the test setup.

Comment: @DanielPryden I just wanted to isolate my unit test from the database. and I just wanted to be assured if it is right way to connect or not connect to the database in such case.

Comment: You don't need to connect to a database to create an ArrayList. You are correct that a unit test should not attempt to connect to a database. Is your issue that your code is not designed to be testable? You should probably add an example of the code you're trying to test.

Comment: @DanielPryden I added example. It seems that I don't need Mockito here.

Comment: @DanielPryden Anyway filling million entries manually doesn't seem good idea too.

Comment: @user6670733 You should write a minimal amount of tests which is necessary to test drive all the code you have. In this case I can see a couple of tests for lists of different sizes: 0, 3, 6 and something not divisible by 3, e.g. 5. This should allow you to cover all the cases (assuming your condition in if-statement is simple, if not you might need more) and you don't need millions of items. By the way, `analyze` method that removes elements from the list passed into it doesn't sound right.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak You are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a test is not a unit test if it talks to the database

You are right.

> So how should I act correctly in this situation?

Create an `ArrayList` object and fill it with data. Then test against this data to assert that your production code behaves as intended. You don't need millions of entries, just the minimum to cover the different cases of `analyze()`.

> how big datas are analyzed by unit tests generally?

A good practice is to have multiple levels of test:

1. Unit tests - verifies the logic of your code, without external resources such as database.
2. Integration test - verifies that different parts of your system (ex: database, web server, api, etc.) interact correctly with one another.
3. Performance tests - verifies how your system behaves under stress or with large volumes of data. There are special tools for this (jMeter, gatling).

Answer (score -2):

Hello you can use like this:
fleResult is your Database or service object that returns the result.
And that class mocked as method param

```
@Test
public void testGetLogEvents(@Mocked final LogRecProcess fleResult,
```

And add @RunWith(JMockit.class) to test class, add Expectations and return your sample data as array

```
new Expectations() {
        {
            fleResult.getEvents();
            result = Arrays.asList(new FilteredLogEvent[] { evnt });
        }
    };
```

Comment: Typos, non-compilable code, some signs of JMock and no signs of Mockito that OP asked about. This answer doesn't seem to be useful at all.

Comment: I have given answer not full code. There is no code given in question to fix it. Typos some one can fix. How do u say this is doesn't seem to be useful at all? Any reason other than typo?